Mimicking signals from automotive sensors using an MCU
I am working on a project that will allow me to test my car's ECU where I have to recreate simultaneous and synchronized signals (Pulses) that should be coming from the camshaft and crankshaft sensors. I will use my DSLogic analyzer to capture those synchronized signals from the actual CAM/CRANCK-Shaft lines and figure out their properties.
I need to regenerate the same exact synchronized camshaft and cranck shaft signals using an MCU (maybe an Arduino, an ESP32, or an STM32). So that I can reinject them into the Car's ECU for diagnosing purposes.
My questions are:

If I capture those signals on my logic analyzer, what is the most efficient and easiest way to reconstruct/recreate and implement the same signals in my code on the MCUs or dev. boards so that the Car's ECU can recognize them?

What is the file extension/ data format I should be using to export my signals from the logic analyzer so that they can be easily implemented/embedded in my code?

Sometimes signals are sinewaves, how can I convert a pulse (square wave) into a sinewave?

Is there any GUI software that allows me to create arbitrary simultaneous and synchronized waveforms?


If you have other ideas please share them!

You probably need to capture the signals first and go from there. As is, your first question is unanswerable as it's "how do I generate an undefined number of undefined signals?"

"Signals" and "sensors" could be anything. You need to narrow this down to one particular type of sensor + signal.

What type of signas are you measuring and from where? Are you doing measurement of engine speed or active current in headlights or tail lights or something else? Different type of signals need different types of circuits which process the signals.  Can you be specific as to which signals you are measuring and from which module and how does the signal look like?

There are typically 50 to 60 ECUs in a car. A MCU OR IC or ASIC in each Electronic control unit gets different types of signals.

I edited the question.

you really need to capture the analog outputs from the sensors because the shape of the waveform may be important

@AmitM I just want to copy the waveforms and be able to regenerate them again using an MCU to be able to inject them into the car's ECU while testing it on the bench.

@jsotola I will use an oscilloscope to check too. But I am quiet sure that the signals I want to measure are Square.
